# Is my variable's lifetime changing due to the addition of an apparently unrelated instruction?

Tags: rust, ownership, borrowing

I'm quite new to Rust, and still reading [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) while writing some simple program every now and then to test what I'm learning.

Today I tried to write a program suggested as an exercise (more precisely the last one at [the end of chapter 8.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch08-03-hash-maps.html)). Since I'm still learning and thus pretty slow, I run a new `cargo build` for almost any new line I add to my `main.rs`. As of now, it looks like this:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};
use std::collections::{HashMap, HashSet};

enum Command<'a> {
    Add {name: &'a str, unit: &'a str},
    List {unit: &'a str},
    Exit
}

fn main() {
    let mut units: HashMap<&str, HashSet<&str>> = HashMap::new();

    loop {
        let mut cmd = String::new();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut cmd).unwrap();

        let cmd = match parse_command(&cmd) {
            Ok(command) => command,
            Err(error) => {
                println!("Error: {}!", error);
                continue;
            }
        };

        match cmd {
            Command::Add {name: new_name, unit: new_unit} => {
                let mut u = units.entry("unit1").or_insert(HashSet::new());
                u.insert(new_name);
            },

            Command::List {unit: target_unit} => {},
            Command::Exit => break
        }
    } // end of loop
} // end of main

fn parse_command<'a>(line: &'a String) -> Result<Command<'a>, &'a str> {
    Ok(Command::Exit)
    // ... still need to write something useful ...
}
```

Nothing complicated, since that I still haven't even wrote anything inside my `parse_command` function, which currently only returns a `Result::Ok(Command::Exit)`, but when I try to compile the above code, I get the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `cmd` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:34:2
   |
17 |            let cmd = match parse_command(&cmd) {
   |                                           --- borrow occurs here
...
34 |    } // end of loop
   |    ^ `cmd` dropped here while still borrowed
35 | } // end of main
   | -  borrowed value needs to live until here
```

It shouldn't be anything strange to figure out, but I'm quite confused by this error. Yes, I drop `cmd` at the end of the `loop`, and that's ok, but **why does the borrowed value need to live until the end of `main`?** Anything related to `cmd` happens inside the `loop`, why is the borrowed value expected to live longer than that?

Trying to figure out what's wrong, I removed the two lines inside the `match` arm of `Command::Add {...}`, so it looks like this:

```
    match cmd {
        Command::Add {name: new_name, unit: new_unit} => {},
        Command::List {unit: target_unit} => {},
        Command::Exit => break
    }
```

and, to my surprise, the code compiled with no error (even though I need those lines so this is just a silly test).

**I thought that these two lines had *nothing* to do with my `cmd` variable, or do they? What's going on here?** I am 99% sure that there's something very silly that I'm missing, but can't figure out what it might be by myself. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes, I drop `cmd` at the end of the loop, and that's ok

No, it's not, and that's what the compiler is telling you. Rust has done its job and prevented you from inserting memory unsafety into your program.

You allocate a `String` inside the loop, *take a reference to it* and make a `Command` from it. `Command` only says that it contains references, all of the same lifetime. The code then takes one of those references back out of `Command` and tries to store it in the `HashMap`.

After the loop exits, the `HashMap` would contain a reference to the now-deallocated `String`, which would be a Very Bad Thing.

> Anything related to `cmd` happens inside the loop

No, it doesn't. You pass the reference to the `String` to a function. At that point, all bets are off. That function can do *anything* allowed by the signature, including:

```
fn parse_command<'a>(line: &'a String) -> Result<Command<'a>, &'a str> {
    Ok(Command::Add {
        name: line,
        unit: line,
    })
}
```

---

Your code is equivalent to:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut units = HashSet::new();

    {
        let cmd = String::new();
        units.insert(&cmd);
    }

    println!("{:?}", units);
}
```

Comment: Oh... I totally forgot that sneaky reference inside the `HashMap`... thank you very much for the detailed answer! Could you suggest a good way of avoiding putting the reference itself inside the hash map? Should I clone the string or something similar?